# MYSQL Display result in single row

Tags: mysql

[image: message table]

[image: response table]

Sorry, my account is new so it's not allowing me to upload more than two images, so [this is the third image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj70V.png).

MySQL query:

```
SELECT  *,
        `message`.`status` as `message_status`,
        `message`.`id` as `message_id`
FROM    `message`
LEFT JOIN
        `pet_info`
ON      `pet_info`.`id` = `message`.`pet_id`
LEFT JOIN
        `response`
ON      `response`.`message_id` = `message`.`id`
WHERE   `user_id` = '1' AND
        `pet_id` = '6'
```

This query displaying me more than 2 rows. I want to display the result in a single row How can I do this please help me.

Comment: Post your images as well formatted text, not as code. That's because links may break (thus making the question useless for future readers) and because that way we won't have to type everything again to set up a working sample